# Monitor has corrupted display at power, then fades to black

Tags: display, repair

I have a Samsung Syncmaster 204B that's displaying garbage on the bottom half of the screen at power-up. After a few seconds, it starts to fade to black -- not uniformly, but spreading out over the course of about five seconds. When the bottom half has all turned black, the backlight goes out for about half a second and then comes on (but still no display on the bottom half). The top half is fine, displaying the "Analog/Digital" no-connection message.

Capacitors on the PSU board have been replaced. I've confirmed that the top board (the one with the LCD flex connectors) is getting a solid 5V throughout. All the flex connectors seem firmly connected.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 variables here:

- The monitor
- Your video card
- The video cable
- The power cable / wall outlet.

Either try a different computer with that monitor and see if the problem persists, or try a different monitor with the same computer, and cables.

I'm betting that your lcd is bad, even though you just replaced the capacitors. If it were under warranty, I would create a RMA however that monitor is from 2006.

You can get a 24 inch for less than $150, or better yet, treat yourself to a 27inch high resolution monitor.

Comment: It's obviously not the video cable or the video card -- it's not even plugged in. It's not the power cable. I was hoping for something a little more granular than "the monitor".

Comment: Ya, unfortunately if the LCD is bad, then there isn't a whole lot you can do.  I've found replacing capacitors works about half the the time. (Which youve already done)You could try fining a replacement circuit board. That will be tough though since yours is from 2006